# How much traffic is real traffic?

Tags: admin

I have my own domain with my own wordpress installation at http://blog.demofox.org

I have both "Count Per Day" and "Jetpack Site Stats" installed and they are usually pretty close in agreement about site stats.

What I'm curious about is how much traffic reported is likely real traffic versus bots and things?

Sometimes I see spikes corresponding to specific posts that make sense as real based on the referers, but usually i have some level of "noise" for posts that I assume can't all be real.

Can anyone speak to how much traffic is likely real traffic?

If this is considered off topic, is there a similar on topic question I can ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all not all websites get the same amount of traffic as others. One of my websites gets like 100 views per day well the other one may get 10.

As per making sure that the stats don't include bots. I have never personally had a problem with bots affecting my page views. If you have two plugins pulling in roughly the same stats then I would assume that they are real statistics.

If the stats are actually spammers or bots hitting your website then there is a way to stop them. The only thing is you need to block by domain. So you can use services like WHOIS.net to figure it out. Then you just need to modify your .htaccess to block them. You can use the following code to achieve that. Add it to your .htaccess.

```
# Block Russian Referrer Spam
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*ilovevitaly\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*ilovevitaly.\.ru/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*ilovevitaly\.org/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*ilovevitaly\.info/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*iloveitaly\.ru/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*econom\.co/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*savetubevideo\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*kambasoft\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*buttons\-for\-website\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*semalt\.com/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*darodar\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]
```

In that code it already has some popular domains that can be spamming it up.

For more details on this I would check out this article. https://moz.com/blog/how-to-stop-spam-bots-from-ruining-your-analytics-referral-data